# How to use a member in the dervied class which assign in the constuctor of the base class?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following base class

Header file

```
class layer_manager_t : public device_t
{
 private:
    layer_manager_t(    
                        int isok_duration_seconds_,
                        int error_recovery_duration_seconds_,
                        const string& alert_server_ipaddr_,

                        int num_frames_to_count_in_ts_clk_est
                        );
 public:
    layer_manager_t( xml::node_t& params ); // the parameter should be const
};
```

Source file:

```
layer_manager_t::layer_manager_t( 
                            int isok_duration_seconds_,
                            int error_recovery_duration_seconds_,
                            const string& alert_server_ipaddr_,
                            int num_frames_to_count_in_ts_clk_est)
{///some code}
```

I have the following derived class:

Header file:

```
class link_layer_manager_t : public layer_manager_t
{
private:

public:

    link_layer_manager_t( xml::node_t& params ); 
    int                   calc_ts_clk_est_duration_seconds_link;
    virtual void calc_ts_clk_est_job_function(void);
};
```

Source file:

```
link_layer_manager_t::link_layer_manager_t( xml::node_t& params ) :
    layer_manager_t(params),
    frq_table_tag(""),
    calc_ts_clk_est_duration_seconds_link(str_to_int(params.get_decendant("ts_clk_est_timer_duration_seconds_link")->text))
{
////some code which contatin a job which call the clalc_job_function
}

void link_layer_manager_t::calc_job_function()
{
  double fraction = 310*(num_frames_to_count_in_ts_clk_est-   1);
}
```

**The params I get in the constructors are drom an xml which I get.

For some reason I get error which said:
"error: 'num_frames_to_count_in_ts_clk_est' was not declared in the scope

Comment: So where is this variable `num_frames_to_count_in_ts_clk_est` declared?  I see parameter named like that, but not variables.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is quite clear, there is no variable `num_frames_to_count_in_ts_clk_est`.

OK, there is one, but it is a parameter to the constructor of `layer_manager_t`, so only the **constructor** of `layer_manager_t` can access that variable.

You would have to create a `protected` variable named `num_frames_to_count_in_ts_clk_est` in `layer_manager_t`, and then assign it to the `num_frames_to_count_in_ts_clk_est` from the constructor.

*Note: `num_frames_to_count_in_ts_clk_est` should be `protected` because you want to have access to it from the  derived class `link_layer_manager_t`*

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I whish there will be more people like you and not like @Captain Obvlious (who laugh beginner.s...shame on you)

Comment: @sarar thanks, but you should really pay more attention to errors and try to understand them. You will learn a lot :)

Comment: @Rakete1111- I will:)